Issue when updating Java 8u431 for ActiveMQ Classic 5.15.0
I need to update Java to version 8u431 on our legacy queuing system, ActiveMQ Classic version 5.15.0.
Currently, we are using JDK 8u131 from 2017 for Windows Server 2012 R2, and everything is working fine. Our setup consists of two Windows servers running in master/slave mode. Ideally, I would like to avoid any service disruption, and upgrading ActiveMQ is not an option at the moment.
My plan is to ensure the master server (amq1) remains available while I update the slave server (amq2). Once amq2 is updated and running, I will switch it to active and then update amq1.
Here are the steps I followed for updating amq2:
Stopped the amq2 service.
Uninstalled the old JRE and JDK.
Installed the new Java version.
Restarted the server.
Verified that the service started and was running.
Stopped amq1 to set amq2 as active.
However, I encountered an issue: even though the service is running, the web portal is unreachable, and the queue handler is timing out.
I checked that java was still available using PowerShell and command line, I restored the server to a snapshot previously taken before any change and the service was back and running. The documentation for this version says it's compatible with all java 8 update.
From the activemq.log before updating:
2024-12-04 14:28:29,772 | INFO  | amqSlave Shutting down NC | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[amqSlave] Task-22600
2024-12-04 14:28:29,772 | INFO  | amqSlave bridge to Unknown stopped | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[amqSlave] Task-22600
2024-12-04 14:28:29,772 | INFO  | error with pending local brokerInfo on: vm://amqSlave#5274 | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[amqSlave] Task-22600
org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: peer (vm://amqSlave#5275) stopped.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.stop(VMTransport.java:233)[activemq-broker-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.stop(TransportFilter.java:72)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.stop(TransportFilter.java:72)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.stop(ResponseCorrelator.java:132)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.doStop(TransportConnection.java:1193)[activemq-broker-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$4.run(TransportConnection.java:1159)[activemq-broker-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_131]
2024-12-04 14:28:29,772 | INFO  | Connector vm://amqSlave stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | Simple Discovery Agent-1083
2024-12-04 14:28:29,772 | WARN  | Could not start network bridge between: vm://amqSlave and: tcp://[AMQ1 dns]:61616/ due to: Connection timed out: connect | org.apache.activemq.network.DiscoveryNetworkConnector | Simple Discovery Agent-1083
2024-12-04 14:28:30,785 | INFO  | Establishing network connection from vm://amqSlave to tcp://[AMQ1 dns]:61616/ | org.apache.activemq.network.DiscoveryNetworkConnector | Simple Discovery Agent-1084
2024-12-04 14:28:30,785 | WARN  | path isn't a valid local location for TcpTransport to use | org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory | Simple Discovery Agent-1084


after updating Java:
2024-12-04 14:31:10,850 | INFO  | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@3a3ddc96: startup date [Wed Dec 04 14:31:10 NZDT 2024]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:31:11,757 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[\\[network drive]\FileServer\ActiveMQ] | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:31:13,338 | INFO  | Database \\[network shared drive]\FileServer\ActiveMQ\lock is locked by another server. This broker is now in slave mode waiting a lock to be acquired | org.apache.activemq.store.SharedFileLocker | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:42:03,492 | INFO  | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@185709da: startup date [Wed Dec 04 14:42:03 NZDT 2024]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:42:04,210 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[\\[network drive]\FileServer\ActiveMQ] | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:42:05,780 | INFO  | Database \\[network shared drive]\FileServer\ActiveMQ\lock is locked by another server. This broker is now in slave mode waiting a lock to be acquired | org.apache.activemq.store.SharedFileLocker | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:42:40,593 | INFO  | KahaDB is version 6 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:42:40,734 | WARN  | Cannot recover message audit | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:42:40,844 | INFO  | Recovering from the journal @1:28 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:42:45,775 | INFO  | @246:20026539, 100000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:42:50,311 | INFO  | @613:14677798, 200000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:42:55,168 | INFO  | @1091:17083049, 300000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:43:00,904 | INFO  | @1382:18954552, 400000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:43:05,717 | INFO  | @1598:22164582, 500000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:43:10,387 | INFO  | @1836:11913893, 600000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:43:15,008 | INFO  | @1912:2901964, 700000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:43:21,329 | INFO  | @1992:13327003, 800000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:43:26,233 | INFO  | @2043:8402549, 900000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:43:31,191 | INFO  | @2194:22789590, 1000000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:43:36,202 | INFO  | @2442:7825165, 1100000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:43:42,624 | INFO  | @2510:3916628, 1200000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:43:47,975 | INFO  | @2715:4467718, 1300000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:43:53,218 | INFO  | @3153:20614525, 1400000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:43:58,966 | INFO  | @3430:24026055, 1500000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:04,711 | INFO  | @3758:11004890, 1600000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:08,945 | INFO  | @3805:10970299, 1700000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:14,937 | INFO  | @4061:3108338, 1800000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:20,823 | INFO  | @4356:33073976, 1900000 entries recovered .. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:21,483 | INFO  | Recovery replayed 1918819 operations from the journal in 100.765 seconds. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:21,639 | INFO  | PListStore:[D:\apache-activemq-5.15.0\bin\win64\..\..\data\amqSlave\tmp_storage] started | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:21,655 | INFO  | Installing ForcePersistencyModeBroker plugin: persistency enforced=true | org.apache.activemq.plugin.ForcePersistencyModeBrokerPlugin | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:21,686 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.0 (amqSlave, ID:[amq2]-52490-1733276560844-0:1) is starting | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,030 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: tcp://[amq2 dns name]:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,030 | INFO  | Connector openwire started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,045 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: amqp://[amq2 dns name]:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,045 | INFO  | Connector amqp started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,045 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: stomp://[amq2 dns name]:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,045 | INFO  | Connector stomp started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,045 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: mqtt://[amq2 dns name]:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,061 | INFO  | Connector mqtt started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,155 | WARN  | ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6653fe4b{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: / | org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,186 | INFO  | Listening for connections at ws://[amq2 dns name]:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.WSTransportServer | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,202 | INFO  | Connector ws started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,202 | INFO  | Establishing network connection from vm://amqSlave to tcp://[amq2 dns]:61616/ | org.apache.activemq.network.DiscoveryNetworkConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,217 | WARN  | path isn't a valid local location for TcpTransport to use | org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,217 | INFO  | Connector vm://amqSlave started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,233 | INFO  | Establishing network connection from vm://amqSlave to tcp://[amq1 dns]:61616/ | org.apache.activemq.network.DiscoveryNetworkConnector | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,233 | WARN  | path isn't a valid local location for TcpTransport to use | org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory | WrapperSimpleAppMain
2024-12-04 14:44:22,295 | INFO  | amqSlave Shutting down NC | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[amqSlave] Task-5
2024-12-04 14:44:22,311 | WARN  | Network connection between vm://amqSlave#0 and tcp://[amq2 DNS]/[amq2 IP address]:61616@52694 shutdown due to a remote error: {} | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://[amq2 DNS]/[amq2 IP address]:61616@52694
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_431]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedInputStream.fill(TcpBufferedInputStream.java:50)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport$2.fill(TcpTransport.java:634)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedInputStream.read(TcpBufferedInputStream.java:59)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport$2.read(TcpTransport.java:619)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:268)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
2024-12-04 14:44:22,311 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://[amq2 IP address]:52694 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///[amq2 IP address]:52694@61616
2024-12-04 14:44:22,311 | INFO  | Network connection between vm://amqSlave#0 and tcp://[amq2 DNS]/[amq2 IP address]:61616@52694 shutdown due to a local error: {} | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | triggerStartAsyncNetworkBridgeCreation: remoteBroker=tcp://[amq2 DNS]/[amq2 IP address]:61616@52694, localBroker= vm://amqSlave#0
java.io.IOException: Stopped.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.stop(ResponseCorrelator.java:131)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.dispose(ServiceSupport.java:43)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.collectBrokerInfos(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:400)[activemq-broker-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.access$500(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:112)[activemq-broker-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport$5.run(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:354)[activemq-broker-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
2024-12-04 14:44:22,311 | INFO  | amqSlave bridge to Unknown stopped | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[amqSlave] Task-5
2024-12-04 14:44:23,325 | INFO  | Establishing network connection from vm://amqSlave to tcp://[amq2 dns]:61616/ | org.apache.activemq.network.DiscoveryNetworkConnector | Simple Discovery Agent-1
2024-12-04 14:44:23,325 | WARN  | path isn't a valid local location for TcpTransport to use | org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory | Simple Discovery Agent-1
2024-12-04 14:44:23,325 | INFO  | amqSlave Shutting down NC | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[amqSlave] Task-13
2024-12-04 14:44:23,325 | INFO  | Network connection between vm://amqSlave#4 and tcp://[amq2 DNS]/[amq2 IP address]:61616@52696 shutdown due to a local error: {} | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | triggerStartAsyncNetworkBridgeCreation: remoteBroker=tcp://[amq2 DNS]/[amq2 IP address]:61616@52696, localBroker= vm://amqSlave#4
java.io.IOException: Stopped.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.stop(ResponseCorrelator.java:131)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.dispose(ServiceSupport.java:43)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.collectBrokerInfos(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:400)[activemq-broker-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.access$500(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:112)[activemq-broker-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport$5.run(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:354)[activemq-broker-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
2024-12-04 14:44:23,325 | WARN  | Network connection between vm://amqSlave#4 and tcp://[amq2 DNS]/[amq2 IP address]:61616@52696 shutdown due to a remote error: {} | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://[amq2 DNS]/[amq2 IP address]:61616@52696
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_431]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedInputStream.fill(TcpBufferedInputStream.java:50)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport$2.fill(TcpTransport.java:634)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedInputStream.read(TcpBufferedInputStream.java:59)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport$2.read(TcpTransport.java:619)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:268)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
2024-12-04 14:44:23,325 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://[amq2 IP address]:52696 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///[amq2 IP address]:52696@61616
2024-12-04 14:44:23,341 | INFO  | amqSlave bridge to Unknown stopped | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[amqSlave] Task-13
2024-12-04 14:44:25,341 | INFO  | Establishing network connection from vm://amqSlave to tcp://[amq2 dns]:61616/ | org.apache.activemq.network.DiscoveryNetworkConnector | Simple Discovery Agent-2
2024-12-04 14:44:25,341 | WARN  | path isn't a valid local location for TcpTransport to use | org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportFactory | Simple Discovery Agent-2
2024-12-04 14:44:25,341 | INFO  | amqSlave Shutting down NC | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[amqSlave] Task-21
2024-12-04 14:44:25,341 | INFO  | Network connection between vm://amqSlave#6 and tcp://[amq2 DNS]/[amq2 IP address]:61616@52703 shutdown due to a local error: {} | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | triggerStartAsyncNetworkBridgeCreation: remoteBroker=tcp://[amq2 DNS]/[amq2 IP address]:61616@52703, localBroker= vm://amqSlave#6
java.io.IOException: Stopped.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.dispose(ServiceSupport.java:43)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.collectBrokerInfos(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:400)[activemq-broker-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.access$500(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:112)[activemq-broker-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport$5.run(DemandForwardingBridgeSupport.java:354)[activemq-broker-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
2024-12-04 14:44:25,341 | WARN  | Network connection between vm://amqSlave#6 and tcp://[amq2 DNS]/[amq2 IP address]:61616@52703 shutdown due to a remote error: {} | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://[amq2 DNS]/[amq2 IP address]:61616@52703
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_431]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedInputStream.fill(TcpBufferedInputStream.java:50)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport$2.fill(TcpTransport.java:634)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpBufferedInputStream.read(TcpBufferedInputStream.java:59)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport$2.read(TcpTransport.java:619)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:268)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_431]
2024-12-04 14:44:25,341 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://[amq2 IP address]:52703 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///[amq2 IP address]:52703@61616
2024-12-04 14:44:25,372 | INFO  | amqSlave bridge to Unknown stopped | org.apache.activemq.network.DemandForwardingBridgeSupport | ActiveMQ BrokerService[amqSlave] Task-21

Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

It's not really true that software based on Java is compatible with all the same major version, especially when you're using application version released 7 years ago.
Suggestions:

Start both amq1 and amq2 nodes - this errors exactly means that network connection between hosts doesn't exist (I guess you doesn't start first node).
Check lib/ext folder at your current java installation path (e.g. c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.431\jre\lib\ext). It can contain specific libraries for some apps that can start at the same time with ActiveMQ or being used by its custom plugins. You'll need to also move it.
Check ActiveMQ configuration and startup command (I guess at services.msc) for any configured plugins which could also be incompatible and should be updated.
Consider upgrade to newer 6.1 or at least currently maintained 5.18.6 ActiveMQ version. Your 5.15.0 version has 11 detected vulnerabilities.

Please feel free to ask comments or another questions!

Hi Andrei, I agree with you about compatibility. I had the node 1 restating at that point but after having both running I still had this issue. I think I would need to check your second and third points but I think I'm going to create a case to do a full upgrade to use artemis and migrating away from windows 2012. Thank you for your time
